# Indentation for plain text bulleted lists in Vim

Tags: vim, indentation

I often write text with a format like this in Vim—

```
- talking point 1

- talking point 2 ....
continue on point 2
```

Ideally, I would hope Vim could auto align it for me such as:

```
- talking point 1

- talking point 2 
  continue on point 2
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've got this in my .vimrc:

```
set comments=s1:/*,mb:*,ex:*/,://,b:#,:%,:XCOMM,n:>,fb:-,fb:[+],fb:[x],fb:[-]
```

If I remember correct, add this line in your .vimrc and the job will be done:

```
set comments +=fb:-
```

For a detailed explanation try:

```
:help comments
```

Comment: The second line did it for me.

Comment: I'm downvoting this, because it seems like an abuse of vim's comment feature—bulleted lists are not comments. vim actually has a built-in feature for lists, so I strongly recommend @Kazark's answer instead. https://superuser.com/a/565514/219388

Answer (score 6):

If you have the `n` flag set in `formatoptions` (e.g. with `set fo+=n`), Vim already knows how to format lists with numeric bullets. `formatlistpat` (short name `flp`) is the regex Vim uses to match this, so what you need is to enhance that regular expression. This should do the trick for you (but only adds support for `-` bullets):

```
set formatlistpat=^\\s*\\(\\d\\+[\\]:.)}\\t\ ]\\|-\\)\\s*
```

Sorry for the backslash headache there. Doing `set flp?` shows more clearly what the regex looks like:

```
formatlistpat=^\s*\(\d\+[\]:.)}\t ]-\)\s*
```

For more information, see [this post](https://superuser.com/q/99138/107337).

Answer (score 0):

```
:set smartindent
```

if you need vim to break the line earlier than add

```
:set tw=30
```

or whatever number of chars per line you need.

Answer (score 0):

See also: http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/vim/formatting/indenting_bullets.html

But also make sure that smartindent/cindent are not also set.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.